# Do I need to include the Install4J license text in my distribution?

Tags: install4j

Do I need to include the Install4J license text (see [here](https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/licensing.html)) in full or in parts when I distribute my commercial software whose installation is based on Install4J?

Neither could I find a `LICENSE.txt` file or something similar in the installation directory, nor did the installer GUI show any Install4J-related license texts.

The Install4J license does not seem to require an explicit listing of the license text but I'm wondering if I should still include some license info on Install4J in my attribution statement which comes with the software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all generated installers and the runtime are freely redistributable, no attribution is required.

Source: https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/licensing.html